# Getting SSLException while payment gateway integration

Tags: java, android, json, web-services, okhttp

I am just integrating  Frimi payment gateway .In first step am trying to generate access tokes ,and after generating tokes payment link will be called .
But am getting error :- SSLException: Connection closed by peer.

```
 public  void TokenGenerationProcess() {
        class WaitingforResponse extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                //  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Waiting for Token Generation...", "Please Wait...", false, false);
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();
                MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

                String json = "";
                RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, json);
               /* https://ideabiz?grant_type=password&username=99R_User&password=99R_User&scope=SANDBOX

                https://igrant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token="+Message+"&scope=SANDBOX */
                // Message="d6a5be5f5455c87c21442ba3d5201c8c";
                Request request = new Request.Builder()
                        .url("https://uatapi.nationstrust.com:8243/token?grant_type=client_credentials")

                        .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                        .addHeader("authorization", "Basic N000SDNmU3RtVERuZmZ1R0JNMlBGR1FXdmtFYTpEQUFJcEprVUhjdXBwcEx4dkRPSkFYZjNwMmth")
                        .post(body)
                        .build();
//Bearer aUFVMWFRd2Vpb2txQUI2VTFkajBFZWRkTTBZYTpEMzZfbU9GM2ZlYkFEaWRiMGp0ZUZCN2xGUUlh")


                try {
                    okhttp3.Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                    String test = response.body().string();
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                       /* int  success = response.code();

                        Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                        for (int i = 0; i < responseHeaders.size(); i++) {

                            System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                        }

                        System.out.println(test);
                        ///   {"scope":"default","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":3600,"refresh_token":"2d23c431f25e10e5abcd16bea931d0a","access_token":"b0bffddb2be384c53135cadf0f565c2"}
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(test);
                            Log.e(" scope", "" + jsonObject.get("scope"));
                            Log.e(" token_type", "" + jsonObject.get("token_type"));
                            Log.e(" expires_in", "" + jsonObject.get("expires_in"));
                            Log.e(" refresh_token", "" + jsonObject.get("refresh_token"));
                            Log.e(" access_token", "" + jsonObject.get("access_token"));
                            // Message = (String) jsonObject.get("refresh_token");

                            String  access_token = (String) jsonObject.get("access_token");
                            String  refresh_token = (String) jsonObject.get("refresh_token");
                            PersistenceManager.saveRefreshToken(getApplicationContext(), refresh_token);
                            PersistenceManager.saveSessionId(getApplicationContext(), access_token);
                            PersistenceManager.saveTime(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
     */                       // reference= (String) jsonObject.get("Refno");

                    } else {
                        System.out.println(test);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                // progressDialog.dismiss();
            }


        }
        WaitingforResponse WaitingforResponse = new WaitingforResponse();
        WaitingforResponse.execute();

    }
```

**See Stacktrace below:**

[image]

// here I have posted full code what I am trying to generate access tokes.
/please help..help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: could you please show us the stacktrace

Comment: I have just attached one image file... whatever the value is coming in logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Please use this it will work 
 OkHttpClient client = null;
                try {
                    client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                            .connectTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                            .sslSocketFactory(new Tls12SocketFactory(), provideX509TrustManager())
                            .build();
                } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

//add this method 
  public X509TrustManager provideX509TrustManager() {
        try {
            TrustManagerFactory factory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            factory.init((KeyStore) null);
            TrustManager[] trustManagers = factory.getTrustManagers();
            return (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0];
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyStoreException exception) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "not trust manager available", exception);
        }

        return null;
    }
//create another java class 

public class Tls12SocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
    private SSLSocketFactory internalSSLSocketFactory;

    public Tls12SocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, null, null);
        internalSSLSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getDefaultCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
        return internalSSLSocketFactory.getSupportedCipherSuites();
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket() throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket());
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(host, port));
    }

    @Override
    public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
        return enableTLSOnSocket(internalSSLSocketFactory.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
    }

    private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
        if(socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
            ((SSLSocket)socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[] {"TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"});
        }
        return socket;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your are not building the call the right way, this is how you should do it.

```
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    MediaType mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, "grant_type=client_credentials");
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url("https://uatapi.nationstrust.com:8243/token")
            .post(body)
            .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
            .addHeader("authorization", "Basic N000SDNmU3RtVERuZmZ1R0JNMlBGR1FXdmtFYTpEQUFJcEprVUhjdXBwcEx4dkRPSkFYZjNwMmth")
            .build();

    try {
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String test = response.body().string();
        if (response.isSuccessful()) {
            System.out.println(test);
        } else {
            System.out.println(response.code() +" : "+ response.message());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Your JSON response will look like this:

```
{
"access_token": "7389a302-82f9-3fa9-b7a3-fefa45d2de32",
"scope": "am_application_scope default",
"token_type": "Bearer",
"expires_in": 500
}
```

**Edit:**

This however does not explain why you are getting the ssl exception. I would need more information to figure that out. What Android OS version is the device are you running your app on. If you are WiFi consider using your mobile network instead.

**Further Edit:**

I see you running version 4.4.2 try run a device with OS version 5.1 upwards. You'll find the problem might go away. If that doesn't make a difference try add this code on your code, make sure it executes before the call is made.

```
public static void initializeSSLContext(Context mContext) {
    try {
        SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        ProviderInstaller.installIfNeeded(mContext.getApplicationContext());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

If that doesn't help, you clearly have a problem with your server's ssl certificates. Try get your server admin to assist.